# Make two directories static in django

Tags: python, django

I have two directories.
static contains javascript and css files. In settings I wrote `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` so they are included correctly.

But also I have folder images which has pretty many images.
My question how can I make folder images also static, because I can't copy into into static.

Thank you.

Comment: creating sub-folders within the static folder is usually routine, e.g. `/static/{css|img|js|fonts}/{files}` but as dm03514 mentioned you _could_ add multiple paths.

Comment: I know that. But I rewrite site usign django and images can't line inside static.

Comment: If this is a real deployed website, just do an `alias` in nginx and dont serve images with Django, its a waste of resources.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

it looks like [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) can take multiple paths:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',
)
```

Comment: I'm knew to this (I mean static files in django). Can you provide a piece of code which will include both static and images as static directories? Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

I wanted to add a static directory called uploads. I tried settings.py first, but it didn't work. However, I managed to turn uploads into a secondary static URL by adding this line to the file urls.py:

```
url(r'^uploads/(?P<path>.*)$', static.serve, {'document_root': settings.BASE_DIR + "/uploads"}),
```

If you get into trouble importing static.serve, this is the line you need to import it:

```
from django.views import static
```

Comment: This comment is underrated, it is a lifesaver when adding for instance directories of generated static html documentation for multiple django apps when you do not want to clutter the settings for the main django instance. Clean and easy, thanks!

Comment: Agree - this answer is underrated - this is the solution which i seekd. thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want two different urls to be static, in my case the development and output directory for my angular2 app, this was my solution, inside your url.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
  # Examples:
  url(r'^', include('website.urls')),

  # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
  urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_DEBUG_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_DEBUG_ROOT)
```

I have several settings.py files, then I symlink to the one I'm using based on the deployment.  Inside my code.settings.py which links to settings.py for writing code, I added:

```
STATIC_DEBUG_URL = '/app/'
STATIC_DEBUG_ROOT = 'xxx/website/app/'
```